# Replacing a pendant light

Tags: electrical, wiring

New light has standard white, black and green wire. In the ceiling there are (2) red wires only.  How do I wire it properly?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the ceiling box?

Comment: We'll need a photo looking up into the ceiling box's innards...

Comment: Can you pull the driver module out of the box and get us some closeups of that? (Leave your existing photo in there, please)

Comment: I pulled out the box out with the white sticker on it and it revealed the white, back and ground.  All set thanks!!!  I never saw a light like this one!

Comment: post that as an answer and I'll upvote it :)

Comment: That module there was a driver for a DC powered light.  Usually the light and driver are a matched set.  Often the driver fails before the light.

Answer (score 1):

I pulled out the box out with the white sticker on it by gently pulling both red wires and it revealed the white, black and ground I was looking for.

Comment: The box could be a driver, ballast, or transformer -- was the old light a LED or something else that does *not* use an Edison screw base?

Comment: Yes, fixture took a 50watt Type T4 (12V-BI-PIN) bulb.  Actually replaced (2) over kitchen island.   They got very hot.  Replaced them with Edison screw base LED bulbs....should save some money on the ol' elec. bill.